# how to get php variable in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I want to get value of $security_code which is in captchaCode.php file, in captcha.php file through javascript.I can not include this file in captcha.php file . Here is the code of Captcha_code.php and this code not comes inside any function of this file:

```
$captcha = new CaptchaCode();
$security_code = str_encrypt($captcha->generateCode(6));
```

And here is my javascript function, through this function i want to get the value of $security:

```
function refresh_captcha()
{
    var img = document.getElementById('captcha_img');
    img.src = '<?php echo "/captcha_images.php"?>';
    jQuery("#captcha_img").attr("src",img.src);
    jQuery("#security_code").val("<?php echo $security_code;?>");
}
```

Actually this code is for getting new encrypted value when captcha is refreshed without refreshing the page.

Comment: you need to use ajax.

Comment: Why do you need to output a static string with php? Why not just write the string in JavaScript?

Comment: Variable should be present in the current file, so you need to include it. Otherwise you have to send request to the .php file and use the answer which is given by it.

Comment: You have two options: Use Ajax to fetch PHP Value, or use cookies

Comment: Could you provide me ajax code..i donot understand how to do this

Comment: you can save security code in an textbox having type=hidden and provide a id and use getElementById method of  javascript

Comment: @komal Is it the right way to store security code in the HTML instead of comparing using sessions?

Comment: Yes i hav taken a hidden input, i want to get the php variable value in that hidden input without include the file . For this i m trying javascript, but still i didn't get the right way.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the image source assignment related code. No need to assign PHP tag. Just assign the PHP file name instead like this.

```
function refresh_captcha()
{
    var img = document.getElementById('captcha_img');
    img.src = '/captcha_images.php';
    jQuery("#captcha_img").attr("src",img.src);
    /*This line will not work without Ajax request*/
    /*jQuery("#security_code").val("<?php echo $security_code;?>");*/
}
```

Comment: @itachi, No, javascript cannot communicate with PHP. It will only have the first value it originally receives.

Comment: @Starx erm.... here javascript doesn't need to do a thing. randomness will be ensure by `php`, not `javascript`.

Comment: @itachi, ????? I am really seeing your point. How does javascript not do a thing here?

Comment: The request to captcha_images.php will be made only once, isn't it?

Comment: my mistake. i thought OP was mentiong about captcha image only. in that case, ajax is overkill, otherwise, ajax is must.

Comment: @itachi, You spinned my head. I was like "What is this guy sayinng?" ha ha

Comment: @itachi I edited code snip and commented the last line where security code is assigned. I don't know what is the purpose OP is thinking in retrieving the security code into HTML.

Answer (score 0):

**In your php file captcha.php,**

```
    $captcha = new CaptchaCode();
    $security_code = str_encrypt($captcha->generateCode(6));?>
    <script>
         var code = '<?= $security_code ?>';
    </script><?php // rest of the php codes
```

**In your js file**

```
function refresh_captcha()
{
    var img = document.getElementById('captcha_img');
    img.src = code;
    jQuery("#captcha_img").attr("src",img.src);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Send an ajax request to a page to output only the code like:

File: outputcode.php (demo only)

```
$captcha = new CaptchaCode();
$security_code = str_encrypt($captcha->generateCode(6));
echo $security_code;
exit;
```

Next, grab that value using AJAX, like for example in jQuery

```
$("#refresh_code").on('click', function() {
   $.get("outputcode.php", function(data) {
      //data will now hold the new code
   });
});
```

Hope this gives you an idea.

Comment: ajax is overkill here. if you want the image to change, changing the img src attribute with a random string is enough.

Comment: its giving error that $ is not defined. If i use jQuery in place of $ then agian its giving error that jQuery is not defined...

Comment: @user2746093, You need to include jQuery library first.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot include the files, you need to use ajax request.

captcha.php

```
$captcha = new CaptchaCode();
$security_code = str_encrypt($captcha->generateCode(6));
echo json_encode($security_code);
```

in your js:

```
<img src="" id="captcha_img" onclick="refresh_captcha()"/>
<script>

    function refresh_captcha()
{
    $.ajax({
        url : 'captcha.php',
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function (security_code) {
            var source = security_code;
            var img = document.getElementById('captcha_img');
            img.src = source;
            jQuery("#captcha_img").attr("src",img.src);
            jQuery("#security_code").val(source);
        }
    });

}
</script>
```

The onclick event on the img could be totally wrong, but for the excercise purpose, I've put it there.

Depends on what $security_code is, you can for example, not use JSON.

Comment: Now its not refreshing the captcha image

Comment: How it should refresh? It refreshes on click on the image in this example.

Comment: m clicking on image but its not refreshing the captcha

Comment: it's changing the src attribute, as far as I can test it, if it's not changing the actual image, there should be another problem

Comment: is there any other way to get the php variable javascript?

Comment: No, I have to do this without session and without cookies.

Comment: Only ajax then. Does the 'src' changes? Can you show us output from js console?

Comment: I have included jquery.

Comment: The provided code works for me, if the PHP code is located in file named `captcha.php`.

Comment: I asked for js console response. Could you provide? When you click on the image with the provided code, it will show error there, if there's any.

Comment: there is an error but its not visible. i mean when i inspect on browser there is one error,when i click on it nothing displays

Comment: This is pretty much impossible, lol. Chrome? Try with firefox, inspect, click on console, reload and click on the image?

Comment: this one display when i click on image..POST http://localhost/Captcha/captcha_images.php [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 2ms]

Comment: Obviously you don't have captcha_images.php in folder captcha, located in your root folder

Comment: Path of the file was incorrect.now i make changes and accurate path display but not works.now it display POST http://localhost/captcha/wp-content/plugins/Captcha/captcha_images.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 20ms]. and there is no error now, but still not working

Comment: what does captcha_images.php returns? Open the file, does it echo the json properly? Maybe you can copy the response here

Comment: $captcha = new CaptchaCode();
$security_code = str_encrypt($captcha->generateCode(6));
echo json_encode($security_code); I used this in captcha_images.php

Comment: only first time.. when i again click on image to refresh it, it doesnot changes

Comment: I mean the file which prints the json, does it change on each refresh?

Comment: So, problem is in your PHP generation of $security_code, it seems that `str_encrypt($captcha->generateCode(6));` returns one and the same value everytime.

Comment: its working in code which i had posted..after making ajax changes, it stops refreshing the captcha

Comment: There are no changes in the PHP file, the only one is that you echo the variable in it. How were you sure before that it's ok, you had never printed it before

Comment: If i undo all the changes that i have done after posting question here then captcha refreshing on image click is working,but i m unable to get the encrypted value which i want during comparison of user entered text with captcha code